# Remove code duplicate in C# like DRY principle

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have code like this:

```
public interface IManager<T> where T : ConnectionOptions

public class XManager : IManager<ConnectionOptions>
{
    private ModuleConnectionOptions _moduleConnectionOptions;
    private void SetConnection(ModuleConnectionOptions moduleConnectionOptions)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        if (currentDirectory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Current directory path is not valid.");
        }

        _moduleConnectionOptions.LocalFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, moduleConnectionOptions.LocalFolder);
    }
}

public class YManager : IManager<ConnectionOptions>
{
    private TestConnectionOptions _testConnectionOptions;
    private void SetConnection(TestConnectionOptions testConnectionOptions)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        if (currentDirectory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Current directory path is not valid.");
        }

        _testConnectionOptions.LocalFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, testConnectionOptions.LocalFolder);
    }
}

public class ConnectionOptions
{
    // empty constructor for serialization
    public ConnectionOptions()
    {
    }

    public ConnectionOptions(string localFolder)
    {
        LocalFolder = localFolder;
    }

    public string LocalFolder { get; set; }
}
```

TestConnectionOptions and ModuleConnectionOptions are child classes of ConnectionOptions and have additional properties.

This code is similar and quite repetitive. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: For any one else stumbling upon this. Please also remember that [Dry is about ideas, not text](http://dearjunior.blogspot.com/2012/03/dry-is-about-ideas-not-text.html) and that [duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)

Comment: by far the simplest without over engineering ... aka an interface , would be to simply change `(ModuleConnectionOptions moduleConnectionOptions)` to `(string localFolder)`

Comment: @span: yes agree. i was like hoping for some way to have abstraction of related ideas than avoiding code duplication with wrong "context". maybe abstract factory pattern. solution below helps to provide clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going into a solution: Do you really need a `Generic` declaration - Always keep in mind the KISS principle and then the DRY. I will remove it altogether from my solution at the end of the post:

I would see the following:

Create the following interface:

```
public interface IConnectionOptions {
    public string LocalFolder {get; set;}
}
```

And have both `TestConnectionOptions` and `ModuleConnectionOptions` implement it. Then drop one class altogether and make one like this:

```
public class Manager : IManager<ConnectionOptions>
{
    private IConnectionOptions connectionOptions;
    private void SetConnection(IConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        if (currentDirectory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Current directory path is not valid.");
        }

        this.connectionOptions.LocalFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, connectionOptions.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

#### No Generic declaration

```
/// Since there is only one instace, no need for generics
public class Manager: IManager
{
    private IConnectionOptions connectionOptions;
    private void SetConnection(IConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        if (currentDirectory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Current directory path is not valid.");
        }

        this.connectionOptions.LocalFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, connectionOptions.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Personally*, I would remove the `IConnectionOptions` interface. Defining interfaces for straight DTOs/property bags is one of my pet peeves. If they're literally straight properties only, what does it mean to have yet another version of it? There's no alternate version/behavior. It's not like you'd need to mock it for testing--you can just create the instance as needed. Obviously I realize you've taken this from the OP.. So it's something for them to consider and likely would've removed the need for the generic to begin with

Comment: modified his code to use a class instead of interface for properties.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation is similar @Athanasios Kataras implementation.
The only difference is the use of abstract generic class and concrete classes for each module.

```
public interface IManager<T> where T : IConnectionOptions
{

}

public abstract class AbcManager<T> : IManager<T> where T: IConnectionOptions
{
    private IConnectionOptions _moduleConnectionOptions;

    protected virtual void SetConnection(IConnectionOptions moduleConnectionOptions)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        if (currentDirectory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Current directory path is not valid.");
        }

        _moduleConnectionOptions.LocalFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, moduleConnectionOptions.LocalFolder);
    }
}

public class XManager : AbcManager<TestConnectionOptions>
{
    
}



public class YManager : AbcManager<ModuleConnectionOptions>
{
    
}

public class TestConnectionOptions : IConnectionOptions
{
    public string LocalFolder { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleConnectionOptions : IConnectionOptions
{
    public string LocalFolder { get; set; }
}

public interface IConnectionOptions
{
    string LocalFolder { get; set; }
}
```